# Исправление пустого дампа БД

Tags: mysql

Приветствую всех вошедших

```
<?php
    //на этом месте код непостижимый моему уму
    echo 'BackUP';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $baza = 'lesson';
    system('mysqldump -u'.$user.' -p'.$pass.' '.$baza.' > '.time().'.sql');
?>
```

Собственно делаю дамп БД - получаю пустой файл. Может кто подсказать, как сделать дамп БД не пустым, а с ее содержимым?

Comment: а если с консоли запустить, то формирует нормальный дамп?

Comment: Простите сударь, на хостинге консоли у меня нет, как и на локальной машине. Да и была бы на локальной - на хостинге все равно консоль не включить. Обидно то, что команда написана простая и по 'мануалу'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system` — Выполняет внешнюю программу и отображает её вывод

Так а посмотерть что возвращает команда религия не позволяет?

```
system('mysqldump -u '.$user.' -p'.$pass.' '.$baza.' > '.time().'.sql', $myVar);
print_r($myVar);
```

**upd:**
пофеншую лучше так:

```
$return_var = NULL;
$output = NULL;
$command = 'mysqldump -u '.$user.' -p'.$pass.' '.$baza.' > '.time().'.sql';
exec($command, $output, $return_var);
if($return_var) { echo "there was an error code: {$return_var}, see the {$output}; }
```

Comment: Ну я атеист вообще, в print_r - вернул только '1' , т.е. просто одну цифру '1'. уже пробовал дополнительно хост прописывать - не помогает.

Comment: обновил_) обратите внимание, что все же между -u и username должен быть пробел
а еще, 1 значит, что произошла какаято ошибка вообщето ;) ну так, jfyi

Comment: очень может быть, что на хостинге нет mysqldump либо команды типа system вообще запрещены. Проще найти класс, который делает дампы баз

Comment: Все понятно теперь. Пойду писать в техподдержку хостинга. Спасибо!

Comment: Так вы сначала проверьте что вам вообще команда пишет? Может увас какието входные данные неверные. Да и врядли хостинг будет ставить чтото...

Comment: А Вы уверены, что с пустым паролем эта штука работает?

Кстати, между паролем и именем базы (lesson) у Вас явно нет пробела.

Вообще, лучше сначала сформируйте текст команды и распечатайте его, а потом уже ее выполняйте.

Comment: да, это тоже не помешало бы конечно)